# Prevent default Permission Inheritence

Tags: permissions, access

Is there a way/setting within SharePoint 2007/10 to prevent newly created sites/pages/etc... from inheriting permissions by default?

Basically I want to create a new "whatever" with a clean slate... no permissions or access.

Thanks,
RaveWolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you are manually creating a site then the parent site permissions will be inherited by default. You will have to manually break inheritance in Site Permission Settings.

However, if you are creating a site programmatically then you can use SPWeb.BreakRoleInheritance(true) method to break inheritance.

Comment: That's really Sad!! but then again that's Microsoft Security for you! I'm not exactly going to open an account and give everyone access and ONLY remove them if I don't want them on there. Anyway, Thank you so much for your prompt response.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from doing it the other way around ? No permissions by default and only give them when you're ready. Althought that'll make you end up with a lot of unique permissions, so it's probably better to move them from a locked library to an open library instead. Which is the way Microsoft prefers to deal with security in SP anyway.

Comment: Also, permissions start inheriting from the SPSite collection level, so if you create that you have a clean container to which noone has access until you give it to them.

Comment: Thanks Cameron... That helps. A clean slate is perfect... The reason is that I _want_ to remove unique permissions (Bare with me here) :). What I am actually doing is creating Groups and adding users there ONLY! Then adding the Groups to Whatever requires access. This way removing "unique" user permissions from individual items.